# How Do I Assign Values of 2 or more Fields in VBScript

Tags: vbscript, erp

Hi sorry for a basic question on VBScript but after scouring the internet. In a If statement I am trying to assign values to 2 fields but when I run this code which is part of an application it does not error neither does it work so I suspect I am doing wrong. Can anyone point me in the right direction as I am trying to assign values to CustomerInformation.CodeObject.Customer and. CustomerInformation.CodeObject.Carrier

```
Function CustomerInformation_OnLoad()
    
    if (SystemVariables.CodeObject.Company = "D" or SystemVariables.CodeObject.Company = "T") and DispatchNoteDetails.CodeObject.Area = "UK" then
        if CustomerInformation.CodeObject.Customer = "AAE02" then
        CustomerInformation.CodeObject.Carrier = "Customer collects" and CustomerInformation.CodeObject.CarrierURN = "AA Driver"
        end if
    end if
    End Function
```

Comment: `CustomerInformation.CodeObject.Carrier = "Customer collects"` in one line, `CustomerInformation.CodeObject.CarrierURN = "AA Driver"` in the next line. No `and`. Two statements are required.(This is vb.Net, isn't it?)

Comment: It's VBScript I have no idea if it's similar to VB.NET...

Comment: @domdew Looks like [SysPro 7](https://help.syspro.com/syspro-7-update-1/ovr-vbscripting.htm) is that what you are using?

Comment: @Flakes is right, you should put each statement on it's own line the `And` operator is used in comparisons not for joining multiple statements together.

Comment: @Lankymart well spotted lol :) it is Syspro 7 and I have just resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi thanks all for the tips.
The code worked when changing to the following:

```
Function CustomerInformation_OnLoad()

if (SystemVariables.CodeObject.Company = "D" or SystemVariables.CodeObject.Company = "T")then
    if CustomerInformation.CodeObject.Customer = "AAE02" then
    CustomerInformation.CodeObject.Carrier = "Customer collects"
    CustomerInformation.CodeObject.CarrierURN = "AA Driver"
    end if
end if
End Function
```

Thanks again for the tips.